# How do I setup a basic VB.NET WinForms application

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I'm want to write a professional application for resale.  I need to know how do I setup a WinForms application with effective error handling?

Answer (score 5):

It is not a trivial task to create a polished application.  It takes much time and experience.

Effective error handling in .NET can be had by handling 'unhandled' thread and domain exceptions.

The following code is an example of an application that does that.  You'll want to derive your own instance of Form.

Buying a good book on the subject would also be an effective way of learning how to do this.

```
Module modMain

    Public Sub Log(ByVal ex As Exception)

        Try

            Dim logDirectory As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Log")
            Dim logName As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"
            Dim fullName As String = IO.Path.Combine(logDirectory, logName)

            If Not IO.Directory.Exists(logDirectory) Then
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(logDirectory)
            End If

            Dim errorString As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") & " >> " & _
                                        ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & _
                                        ex.StackTrace & Environment.NewLine

            IO.File.AppendAllText(fullName, errorString)

        Catch ignore As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub ThreadExceptionHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
        Log(e.Exception)
    End Sub

    Public Sub DomainExceptionHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        Dim ex As Exception = CType(e.ExceptionObject, Exception)
        Log(ex)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Main()

        AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThreadExceptionHandler
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)

        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf DomainExceptionHandler

        Try
            Application.Run(New Form)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log(ex)
        Finally
            RemoveHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThreadExceptionHandler
            RemoveHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf DomainExceptionHandler
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: +1 Here's a link to the sample code in the MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would start by purchasing books (or tutorials) that match your learning pace. But bear in mind there is often a gap between being able to create an application, and being able to create a 'polished' application. You won't get that from books; you get that from creating lots of apps!

Here's a decent place to start (and it's free): [Visual Basic Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/default.aspx)

From that site: [Learning Visual Basic from the Ground Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789086.aspx)

Once you become familiar with the basics, take a look at [windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net/)